# Передача значений datagridview в combobox!

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

И так у меня имеется две формы 'Base' и 'Sort'. На форме 'Base' есть кнопка для перехода на другую форму и 'datagridview'.  На форме 'Sort', сидят два объекта combobox. Что в итоге мне необходимо?  Мне необходимо вынесение из 'datagridview' значения двух столбцов в 'combobox'-сы, чтобы провести сортировку по этим двум столбцам. Но при этом сами 'combobox'-сы находиться на другой форме.  Язык C# и FrimeWork 4.5.2. Я уже попробовал делать через ссылку, но всё равно ошибку выдает, менял значение с 'private' на 'public'. И всё равно пусто.

Comment: язык-то какой используете и фреймворк?

Comment: фреймворк 4.5 а язык C#